# Python, Using the result of a local variable in another class?

Tags: python

making an attempt to get my head around Python.
Reasonable experience with Excel and HTML.
This is my first attempt at a Python program and its a card game.
I need to understand how to use the value generated in the "first_random_card" Class "random_card1", in another Class, "second_random_card".
The Second_random_card, will have a "Drawing Tableau" referencing the value of Random Card1. Depending on the value of "random_card1" will determine the what the player 2 can do.

```
class first_random_card(object):
"""The first players random card and its results"""

def __init__(self): 

    shuffle1 = random.randint(1, 52)#<- Generates a random number 1 to 52.
    if shuffle1 < 10:
        random_card1 = (shuffle1)
    elif shuffle1 > 9 and shuffle1 < 14:
        random_card1 = (0)
    elif shuffle1 > 13 and shuffle1 < 23:
        random_card1 = (shuffle1 - 13)
    elif shuffle1 > 22 and shuffle1 < 27:
        random_card1 = (0)
    elif shuffle1 > 26 and shuffle1 < 36:
        random_card1 = (shuffle1 - 26)
    elif shuffle1 > 35 and shuffle1 < 40:
        random_card1 = (0)
    elif shuffle1 > 39 and shuffle1 < 49:
        random_card1 = (shuffle1 - 39)
    elif shuffle1 > 48 and shuffle1 <= 52:
        random_card1 = (0)

        print("1st Random Card =", random_card1)
    #The value of random card 1 will now be a range of 0 to 9
    #which is used for scoring purposes.
    #The value of shuffle1 is used to select an image to display a card    

class second_random_card():
"""The second players random card and its results"""
#so I need to define "random_card1" here.
#Ie, first_random_card = random_card1
```

Thank you for helping an obvious newbie with what is probably going to be a simple solution :)

Comment: you have 8 different if/elif's but   `random_card` is  always  set to the same value?

Comment: Thanks for your comment Padraic, random_card's value will be between 0 and 9. So for example, random.randint returned 40, random card will be 40 - 39 = 1.

Answer (score 2):

No no no, you're approaching this all wrong. Let me first answer the literal question, then I'll go into a *much* better way to do this. To access the result of an object's method, use `return`, and access it like you would any other function's results.

```
class ExampleClass(object):
    def some_method(self, some_arg):
        return some_arg * 42

foo = ExampleClass()
result = foo.some_method(12)
# result is now 504

# This is synonymous to:
def some_function(some_arg):
    return some_arg * 42
result2 = some_function(12)
```

Secondly you're thinking FAR too small. You're defining a class for a player's *first* random card. There's literally only going to be a couple of these ever, and they fit neatly into a bigger circle: "Card." Just define a `Card` class and let that do the work for you.

```
class Card(object):
    def __init__(self, cardnum=None):
        # cardnum=None and the statements below let you explicitly create a card
        # rather than allow it to be randomly generated. Makes testing much easier!
        if cardnum is None:
            cardnum = random.randint(1,52)
        self.cardnum = cardnum

    def get_first_random_card(self):
        rank = self.cardnum % 13
        if rank >= 10:
            rank = 0
        # this is actually your whole if/elif/else statement!
        return rank

c = Card(17)  # explicitly defined so it's easier to follow
result = c.get_first_random_card()  # 4
```

And once you start looking at it, you realize you can have a bunch of Card objects and they'll keep their state once initialized. Let's just throw it all in `__init__` and give them a `rank` attribute

```
class Card(object):
    def __init__(self, cardnum=None):
        if cardnum is None:
            cardnum = random.randint(1,52)
        self.cardnum = cardnum
        rank = self.cardnum % 13
        if rank >= 10:
            rank = 0
        self.rank = rank

c = Card(17)
c.rank  # 4
```

Now (just as food for thought) you'll notice that you can randomly get the same card more than once, which doesn't make much sense if you're dealing with a standard deck of playing cards. You could also define a class `Deck` that handles all the cards. Maybe something like:

```
class Deck(object):
    def __init__(self, decksize=52, container_factory=Card):
        self.decksize = decksize
        self.container_factory = container_factory
        self.shuffle()

    def draw(self):
        """Draw a card from the top of the deck"""
        card = self.stub.pop()
        self.used.append(card)
        return card

    def shuffle(self):
        self.stub = [self.container_factory(i) for i in 
                     range(1, self.decksize)+1]
        self.used = []
        random.shuffle(self.stub)
```

Comment: Hey Adam, really appreciate the effort you put into your reply... What I am working on here is a training module for a game using 8 decks of cards. So seeing the same result is to be expected. As I mentioned before, the "shuffle1" result, 1 - 52 is used to display a gif file of the chosen card using the following  photo1 = tkinter.PhotoImage(file=image_dir+"/"+str(shuffle1)+".gif")                           I then need to give a value of 0 to 9, for score value of the card, as follows. Face Value of cards 2 to 9 = their face value. 10, J, Q, K = 0 and Ace =1. Hence the method I used.